# SharePoint web app development

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am new to Microsoft Sharepoint. The requirement is this, I want to create a web site that lets users upload their CVs and, some other users (let's say reviewers) to review them and give them feedback. (Feedback should be sent to users by email)

All the users and reviewers will have office 365 accounts and that can be used for login.

So my question is; is there any built in services or any kind of add-ins that is there in SharePoint that would let me create this OR should I write a separate app in Visual Studio for this.

I am new to Sharepoint and Web Development as well. I know this kind of thing can be easily done using a simple web application but the client wants that to be done in Sharepoint.

Sorry if this is a silly question. I have spent a lot of time researching about what sharepoint is. But I couldn't get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your requirements , you need to create a site with upload document and collect feedback features , in this case, I think you can achieve this as out of the box (no code required) if you have `SharePoint Online for Office 365 for enterprises`, by doing the following :

- Create a site.for more detail check [how-to-create-a-new-sharepoint-online-site-collection](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/how-to-create-a-new-sharepoint-online-site-collection/)
- Create a list with your required fields.
- Create a SharePoint Group for reviewers.
- On this list , create a build in a workflow to collect feedback. for more details check [All-about-Collect-Feedback-workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Collect-Feedback-workflows-e0443930-6a88-4f71-ac4e-6ab591225066)

**Note :** As I above-mentioned `Collect Feedback workflows` are included only with SharePoint Server 2010 and with SharePoint Online for Office 365 for enterprises. (They aren’t included with SharePoint Online for Office 365 for small businesses and professionals. The only SharePoint workflow included with SharePoint Online for small businesses is the Three-state workflow.).

If you don't use a SharePoint Online for Office 365 for enterprises, you can build your custom workflow via SharePoint designer or use the only available  `three State workflow`. for more details check [creating-custom-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer-2013](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/creating-custom-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer-2013.cfm)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read the article and inbuilt feedback workflow seems to be not customized well. I have some criteria to follow as well. CV document should be restricted to .pdf. And a user only able to upload a CV once and if he want he can replace his old file. Further reviewers are shown CVs randomly 5 or 6 at a time. 
Will I able to achieve these? Sorry if this is too broad. If you can please suggest me a place to learn more about sharepoint.

Comment: In this case, I think this is will be the responsibility of reviewers , I try to don't let you write code , but if you need to do this additional requirements so  besides the above steps you will need to create a Remote Event Receiver to check the uploaded file type and check if he upload a document before or not  for more details checks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification